controller manager - could not enable FIFO RT scheduling policy with error number <1>(Operation not permitted)
I have been working in ros2 humble, i encountered the realtime kernel installation issue at first, after that this warning comes up when executing the launch file
$ ros2 launch round_bot visualize.launch.py 
[INFO] [launch]: All log files can be found below /home/pc/.ros/log/2024-11-03-10-49-37-779780-pc-10308
[INFO] [launch]: Default logging verbosity is set to INFO
[INFO] [rviz2-1]: process started with pid [10311]
[INFO] [robot_state_publisher-2]: process started with pid [10313]
[INFO] [joint_state_publisher-3]: process started with pid [10315]
[robot_state_publisher-2] 1730611178.000255 [0] robot_stat: selected interface "lo" is not multicast-capable: disabling multicast
[rviz2-1] Warning: Ignoring XDG_SESSION_TYPE=wayland on Gnome. Use QT_QPA_PLATFORM=wayland to run on Wayland anyway.
[robot_state_publisher-2] [INFO] [1730611178.007105136] [robot_state_publisher]: got segment back_caster_link
[robot_state_publisher-2] [INFO] [1730611178.007215197] [robot_state_publisher]: got segment base_link
[robot_state_publisher-2] [INFO] [1730611178.007228044] [robot_state_publisher]: got segment camera_link
[robot_state_publisher-2] [INFO] [1730611178.007237240] [robot_state_publisher]: got segment camera_link_optical
[robot_state_publisher-2] [INFO] [1730611178.007245863] [robot_state_publisher]: got segment chassis
[robot_state_publisher-2] [INFO] [1730611178.007253982] [robot_state_publisher]: got segment front_caster_link
[robot_state_publisher-2] [INFO] [1730611178.007262607] [robot_state_publisher]: got segment left_wheel
[robot_state_publisher-2] [INFO] [1730611178.007270860] [robot_state_publisher]: got segment lidar_link
[robot_state_publisher-2] [INFO] [1730611178.007279022] [robot_state_publisher]: got segment mount_link
[robot_state_publisher-2] [INFO] [1730611178.007286954] [robot_state_publisher]: got segment right_wheel
[rviz2-1] 1730611178.081721 [0]      rviz2: selected interface "lo" is not multicast-capable: disabling multicast
[rviz2-1] [INFO] [1730611178.195803681] [rviz2]: Stereo is NOT SUPPORTED
[rviz2-1] [INFO] [1730611178.196392230] [rviz2]: OpenGl version: 4.6 (GLSL 4.6)
[rviz2-1] [INFO] [1730611178.225605498] [rviz2]: Stereo is NOT SUPPORTED
[joint_state_publisher-3] 1730611178.235476 [0] joint_stat: selected interface "lo" is not multicast-capable: disabling multicast
[joint_state_publisher-3] [INFO] [1730611178.264788415] [joint_state_publisher]: Waiting for robot_description to be published on the robot_description topic...
[rviz2-1] [INFO] [1730611178.348349442] [rviz2]: Stereo is NOT SUPPORTED
[INFO] [ros2_control_node-4]: process started with pid [10386]
[ros2_control_node-4] 1730611183.010602 [0] ros2_contr: selected interface "lo" is not multicast-capable: disabling multicast
[ros2_control_node-4] [INFO] [1730611183.018761307] [controller_manager]: Subscribing to '~/robot_description' topic for robot description file.
[ros2_control_node-4] [INFO] [1730611183.019066233] [controller_manager]: update rate is 100 Hz
[ros2_control_node-4] [WARN] [1730611183.019204012] [controller_manager]: Could not enable FIFO RT scheduling policy: with error number <1>(Operation not permitted). See [https://control.ros.org/master/doc/ros2_control/controller_manager/doc/userdoc.html] for details on how to enable realtime scheduling.

I referred this ros2 documentation to configure the SCHED_FIFO as it suggested. the limits.conf file. And ofcourse, i added the realtime group before the limits.conf file changed.
# /etc/security/limits.conf
#
#Each line describes a limit for a user in the form:
#
#<domain>        <type>  <item>  <value>
#
#Where:
#<domain> can be:
#        - a user name
#        - a group name, with @group syntax
#        - the wildcard *, for default entry
#        - the wildcard %, can be also used with %group syntax,
#                 for maxlogin limit
#        - NOTE: group and wildcard limits are not applied to root.
#          To apply a limit to the root user, <domain> must be
#          the literal username root.
#
#<type> can have the two values:
#        - "soft" for enforcing the soft limits
#        - "hard" for enforcing hard limits
#
#<item> can be one of the following:
#        - core - limits the core file size (KB)
#        - data - max data size (KB)
#        - fsize - maximum filesize (KB)
#        - memlock - max locked-in-memory address space (KB)
#        - nofile - max number of open file descriptors
#        - rss - max resident set size (KB)
#        - stack - max stack size (KB)
#        - cpu - max CPU time (MIN)
#        - nproc - max number of processes
#        - as - address space limit (KB)
#        - maxlogins - max number of logins for this user
#        - maxsyslogins - max number of logins on the system
#        - priority - the priority to run user process with
#        - locks - max number of file locks the user can hold
#        - sigpending - max number of pending signals
#        - msgqueue - max memory used by POSIX message queues (bytes)
#        - nice - max nice priority allowed to raise to values: [-20, 19]
#        - rtprio - max realtime priority
#        - chroot - change root to directory (Debian-specific)
#
#<domain>      <type>  <item>         <value>
#

#*               soft    core            0
#root            hard    core            100000
#*               hard    rss             10000
#@student        hard    nproc           20
#@faculty        soft    nproc           20
#@faculty        hard    nproc           50
#ftp             hard    nproc           0
#ftp             -       chroot          /ftp
#@student        -       maxlogins       4

#@realtime soft rtprio 99
#@realtime soft priority 99
#@realtime soft memlock 102400
#@realtime hard rtprio 99
#@realtime hard priority 99
#@realtime hard memlock 102400

# End of file

logged out and log in, still the warning persist. Does this warning change anything in work flow of the controller_manager? is it okay to let it be?
the kernel version i have is
Linux pc 5.15.0-1072-realtime #80-Ubuntu SMP PREEMPT_RT Thu Oct 3 16:00:12 UTC 2024 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

the output of the getent group command
root:x:0:
daemon:x:1:
.
.
.
snap_daemon:x:584788:
realtime:x:1001:pc


Yes, this warning does not do anything wrong in the process. The warning never appeared again.
